# Name changing and mazal with 2 of our fathers and 1 mother

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, imahot-matriarch-mothers

The Talmud (appreciate if someone can edit the location) says that one way to change one's *mazal* is to change his / her name.

Avram became Avraham; Sarai became Sarah and Ya'akov became Yisrael.

Did each of these people have their mazal changed as a result? If so, in what way?

Comment: Well, Avraham and Sarah had a son.

Comment: @Scimonster valid point. The question is if there's a correlation. I.e., did that name change cause that to occur.

Comment: For Avraham and Sarah check out Rashi on Bereishit 15:5

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11031/9682

Comment: @DanF There's correlation, the question is causality! ;-)

Comment: @Kazibácsi Indeed, as the answer below indicates. It's actually the "reverse". The Gemarah learns the rule from something that happened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Talmud states that changing one's name can tear up the decree against them, and derives this from Sarah who had a child after her name was changed:

**[Rosh Hashana 16b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=16b&format=pdf)**

> וא"ר יצחק ד' דברים מקרעין גזר דינו של אדם אלו הן צדקה צעקה שינוי השם
>   ושינוי מעשה צדקה דכתיב וצדקה תציל ממות צעקה דכתיב ויצעקו אל ה' בצר להם
>   וממצוקותיהם יוציאם שינוי השם דכתיב שרי אשתך לא תקרא את שמה שרי כי שרה
>   שמה וכתיב וברכתי אותה וגם נתתי ממנה לך בן שינוי מעשה דכתיב וירא האלהים
>   את מעשיהם וכתיב וינחם האלהים על הרעה אשר דבר לעשות להם ולא עשה וי"א אף
>   שינוי מקום דכתיב ויאמר ה' אל אברם לך לך מארצך והדר ואעשך לגוי גדול
>   ואידך ההוא זכותא דא"י הוא דאהניא ליה
>
> R. Isaac further said: Four things cancel the doom of a man, namely,
>   charity, supplication, change of name and change of conduct. Charity,
>   as it is written, And charity delivereth from death. Supplication, as
>   it is written, Then they cried unto the Lord in their trouble, and he
>   delivered them out of their distresses. Change of name, as it is
>   written, As for Sarai thy wife, thou shalt not call her name Sarai,
>   but Sarah shall her name be; and it continues, And I will bless her
>   and moreover I will give thee a son of her. Change of conduct, as it
>   is written, And God saw their works, and it continues, and God
>   repented of the evil which he said he would do unto them and he did it
>   not. Some say that change of place [also avails], as it is written,
>   Now the Lord said unto Abram, Get thee out of thy country, and it
>   proceeds, and I will make of thee a great nation. And the other [ —
>   why does he not reckon this]? — In that case it was the merit of the
>   land of Israel which availed him. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Rosh_HaShanah.pdf))

The Talmud elsewhere cites Avraham overcoming his "*mazal*" to have a child as proof that there is no *mazal* for Israel:

**[Shabbat 156a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=156&format=pdf)**

> ואף רב סבר אין מזל לישראל דאמר רב יהודה אמר רב מניין שאין מזל לישראל
>   שנאמר ויוצא אותו החוצה אמר אברהם לפני הקב"ה רבש"ע בן ביתי יורש אותי
>   אמר לו לאו כי אם אשר יצא ממעיך אמר לפניו רבש"ע נסתכלתי באיצטגנינות שלי
>   ואיני ראוי להוליד בן אמר ליה צא מאיצטגנינות שלך שאין מזל לישראל מאי
>   דעתיך דקאי צדק במערב מהדרנא ומוקמינא ליה במזרח והיינו דכתיב מי העיר
>   ממזרח צדק יקראהו לרגלו
>
> Rab too holds that Israel is immune from planetary influence. For Rab
>   Judah said in Rab's name: How do we know that Israel is immune from
>   planetary influence? Because it is said, and he brought him forth from
>   abroad. Abraham pleaded before the Holy One, blessed be He, ‘Sovereign
>   of the Universe! one born in mine house is mine heir.’ ‘Not so,’ He
>   replied, ‘but he that shall come forth out of thine own bowels.’
>   ‘Sovereign of the Universe!’ cried he, ‘I have looked at my
>   constellation and find that I am not fated to beget child.’ ‘Go forth
>   from [i.e., cease] thy planet [gazing], for Israel is free from
>   planetary influence. What is thy calculation? Because Zedek [Jupiter]
>   stands in the West? I will turn it back and place it in the East.’ And
>   thus it is written, Who hath raised up Zedek from the east? He hath
>   summoned it for his sake. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Shabbath.pdf))

Another midrashic source goes a step further and says that it was specifically Avraham's name change that allowed him to overcome the *mazal*:

**Bereishit Rabbah 44:10**

> אמר רב שמואל בר רב יצחק המזל דוחקני ואומר לי אברם אין את מוליד א"ל
>   הקב"ה הן כדבריך אברם לא מוליד אברהם מוליד שרי אשתך לא תקרא שמה שרי שרי
>   לא תלד שרה תלד

In other words, it was specifically Avram that could not have a child, but Avra**ha**m could have a child.

A slight issue with this is that Avraham already had a child (Yishmael) before his name-change. This is addressed by [R. Eliyahu Mizrachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah_Mizrachi) who argues that the midrash does not mean that Avram could not have a child at all; rather, it means that he could not have a child who would be fitting to inherit him:

**Mizrachi Bereishit 15:5**

> ואינו ר"ל אברם אינו מוליד כלל שהרי הוליד את ישמעאל טרם שנקרא שמו אברהם
>   אלא ה"פ אברם אינו מוליד בן הראוי ליורשו אברהם מוליד בן הראוי ליורשו

As for Yaakov, the Talmud elsewhere tells us that his name was not actually changed; rather, he was just given an additional name:

**[Berachot 12b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=12b&format=pdf)**

> כיוצא בו אתה אומר לא יקרא שמך עוד יעקב כי אם ישראל יהיה שמך לא לא
>   שיעקר יעקב ממקומו אלא ישראל עיקר ויעקב טפל לו
>
> Similarly you read: Thy name shall not be called any more Jacob, but
>   Israel shall be thy name. This does not mean that the name Jacob shall
>   be obliterated, but that Israel shall be the principal name and Jacob
>   a secondary one. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))